# GPUImage change img Color temperature

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I have a UIImage read form album，and do something with GPUImage like:

```
GPUImagePicture* picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:srcImage]; // srcImage is an UIImage
GPUImageFilter *resultFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
[picture addTarget:resultFilter];
[resultFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[picture processImage];
UIImage* resultImg = [resultFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

or

```
GPUImageFilter *resultFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
[resultFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
resultImg = [resultFilter imageByFilteringImage:srcImage];
```

What i expect is srcImage is fully equal to the resultImg， because GPUImagePicture and GPUImageFilter do nothing，but the result is the color temperature of resultImg is colder than srcImage